# ERROR: com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: JDBC_52 - Error starting LogMiner

Tags: streamsets

I am getting the following error while running oracle cdc since today morning it was running fine but get continues errors from this morning.

What is the exact reason for this error?

The pipeline, cdc_test stopped at 2019-06-15 13:37:46 due to the following error:

```
UNKNOWN com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: JDBC_52 - Error
starting LogMiner at
com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.jdbc.cdc.oracle.OracleCDCSource.startGeneratorThread(OracleCDCSource.java:454)
at
com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.jdbc.cdc.oracle.OracleCDCSource.produce(OracleCDCSource.java:325)
at
com.streamsets.pipeline.api.base.configurablestage.DSource.produce(DSource.java:38)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.lambda$execute$2(StageRuntime.java:283)
at
com.streamsets.pipeline.api.impl.CreateByRef.call(CreateByRef.java:40)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.execute(StageRuntime.java:235)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.execute(StageRuntime.java:298)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StagePipe.process(StagePipe.java:219)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunner.processPipe(ProductionPipelineRunner.java:810)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunner.runPollSource(ProductionPipelineRunner.java:554)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunner.run(ProductionPipelineRunner.java:383)
at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:527)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipeline.run(ProductionPipeline.java:109)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunnable.run(ProductionPipelineRunnable.java:75)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.standalone.StandaloneRunner.start(StandaloneRunner.java:703)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.AbstractRunner.lambda$scheduleForRetries$0(AbstractRunner.java:349)
at
com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:226)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:33)
at
com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at
com.streamsets.datacollector.metrics.MetricSafeScheduledExecutorService$MetricsTask.run(MetricSafeScheduledExecutorService.java:100)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01291: missing logfile ORA-06512: at
"SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR", line 58 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this means that while the pipeline was stopped, Oracle deleted one or more logfiles, so the pipeline cannot pick up where it left off.

This blog entry gives a lot of detail on the issue and steps to resolve it: https://streamsets.com/blog/replicating-oracle-mysql-json#ora-01291-missing-logfile